# intercepting the box

Tags: cryptography

If you need to send a message in a box to a person so that no one can intercept it and get the message, how do you do so if you have a padlock and key and they have a padlock and key

Answer (score 0):

This solution has the box being locked anytime it's in transit, and does not require any exchange of keys:

> A puts the message in the box, padlocks it, and sends it to B.
>
>  B padlocks the box, and sends it back to A.
>
>  A unlocks their padlock and sends the still-locked box back to B.
>
>  B unlocks their padlock and opens the box.

Comment: The first thing we're going to do is to rotate all those discs as far *clockwise* as they'll go. Then, I'm going to get the pick Bosnian Bill and I made..